# React js jquery integration error while using sumo select

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from "jquery";

class Test2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected:[],
      showerror:false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    $('.testselect7').SumoSelect({ okCancelInMulti: true });
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <select class="testselect1" placeholder="this is placeholder">
            <option>selected</option>
            <option>Volvo</option>
            <option>Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default Test2
```

Here i am trying to intregrate jquery with reactjs and i have added my cdn in my index.html file.
But it giving me below error:

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).SumoSelect is not a function
```

Please have  a look.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command 
`npm i sumoselect` and
add `$.SumoSelect = require('sumoselect');` in the `import` section